# Android Campaign Parameters not working

Tags: android, google-analytics

I am trying to test play store tracking parameter on my android application.

I have updated the manifest file with following code

```
<!-- Optionally, register AnalyticsReceiver and AnalyticsService to support background
     dispatching on non-Google Play devices -->
<receiver android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.AnalyticsReceiver"
    android:enabled="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.ANALYTICS_DISPATCH" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
<service android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.AnalyticsService"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="false"/>

<!-- Optionally, register CampaignTrackingReceiver and CampaignTrackingService to enable
     installation campaign reporting -->
<receiver android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingReceiver"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
<service android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingService" />

<!-- ... -->
```

I am passing the following command through terminal

```
adb shell am broadcast -a com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER -n com.example.pranav.ui/com.google.analytics.tracking.android.CampaignTrackingReceiver --es "referrer" "utm_source=pranav&utm_medium=testMedium&utm_term=testTerm&utm_content=testContent&utm_campaign=testCampaign"
```

I am receiving the following response from adb shell

> Broadcasting: Intent { act=com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER
>   cmp=com.example.pranav.ui/com.google.analytics.tracking.android.CampaignTrackingReceiver
>   (has extras) } Broadcast completed: result=0

Everything is happening upto this point as per the guide given on https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/testing-play-campaigns

But instead of getting the campaign parameter I am receiving the following on Logcat

> AnalyticsReceiver is not registered or is disabled. Register the
>   receiver for reliable dispatching on non-Google Play devices

Comment: any solution? did you find out the problem?

Comment: Interested in a solution here too - this is exactly the same problem I'm having.